# Neocons Cypher tquery and accessing values from keys

Tags: neo4j, cypher

After calling neo4j with neocons (cy/tquery conn node-query {:_nodeid _nodeid}), how do you perform accessing functions to get property values from the keys that are returned from the neo4j datastore response?

For example if this object was the response from the neo4j datastore, what neocons syntax do I use to access the value stored in key "attributes"?

```
[ {
  "id": "letter-a",
  "name": "Letter A",
  "attributes": [ ... ]
}]
```

Currently I can only get so far as (first _response) but (get-in (first _response) [:attributes]) is giving me back nil

---

******************* EDIT *******************************

---

Here is the cypher query string I use as an argument to invoke the tquery function:

```
(def node-query "MATCH (n)-[attributelist:RELATIONSHIPTYPE]->(target)
                 RETURN n.id          AS id, 
                        n.name        AS name, 
                        COLLECT({
                          target    : target.id
                        })            AS attributes;")
```

I don't understand what type of variable tquery returns? It looks like this object when the client displays it all the way in the browser:

```
[
  {
    "id": "node-999990a0a0a0sa0",
    "name": "Node Name",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "target": "node-id-one"
      },
      {
        "target": "node-id-two"
      },
      {
        "target": "node-id-two"
      },
      {
        "target": "node-id-two"
      },
      {
        "target": "node-id-three"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But I want to intercept what is returned from the tquery before the clojure server delivers it to the client and I want to manipulate the array value of the key "attributes" so I can run a reduce (tally) report before I deliver a rebuilt object response to the client.

```
{
    ...
    "attributes" : {
        "node-id-one"     : 1,
        "node-id-two"     : 3,
        "node-id-three"   : 1
    }
}
```

But I am having trouble because I do not know the syntax to access the "attributes" key from the object that is returned from the tquery

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't understand your question. Which query did you run with tquery?

Usually you return the data you're interested in directly from the query.

e.g

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m) 
WHERE p.name = "Tom Hanks" 
RETURN m.title, m.released`
```

Otherwise you'd have to requery using a label+unique-property

```
MATCH (m:Movie) 
WHERE m.title = "The Matrix"
RETURN m.title, m.released`
```

or node-id match.

```
MATCH (m:Movie) 
WHERE id(m) = 123
RETURN m.title, m.released`
```

You usually would use parameters instead of literal values, i.e. `{name}`, `{title}`, `{id}`.

#### Update

I think for intercepting you would have to look into the neocons implementation.

**Note:** there is no clojure server, it's a Neo4j server with an http endpoint.

You should be able to do what you want (almost) in cypher.

```
MATCH (n)-[:RELATIONSHIPTYPE]->(target)
WITH n, target.id as target, count(*) as c
RETURN n.id as id, n.name as name, collect([target,c]) as targets;
```

Unfortunately right now there are no dynamic map-keys in Cypher, so a tuple-collection will have to do.

### PS

You should use a label at least for your `n` (and optionally `target`) nodes.

Comment: thank you for your guidance Michael. As per michaelklishin, this draws values from a map returned by tquery: (get-in _response [0 "attributes"])